# Rendering Backbone.js view with template variable undefined in the model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is it possible from a backbone.js view to render an underscore.js template with a variable that is not defined in the related Backbone.js model?

take the `can't find variable: username` error.

the template to be rendered:

```
<div class="content" id="content">               
<div id="form">
    <form action="">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value= <%=username%> >
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" >
        <ul class="table-view">
            <li class="table-view-cell">
                Remember me
                <div class="toggle active">
                    <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button id="logbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>    

<button id="renregbtn" class="btn btn-positive btn-block">Register</button>
</div>
</div>
```

rendering line from the view:

```
this.$el.html( this.template_login( this.loginModel ) );
```

line form the loginModel model file:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: '/login',
            initialize: function(){
                this.fetch();
            },
        });

        return LoginModel;
});
```

I set the model manually. But still take the can't find variable error as in the first render case.

same model above:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: '/login',
            defaults: {
                username: "abc",
            },
            initialize: function(){
                this.fetch();
            },
        });

        return LoginModel;
});
```

Both cases result in:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: username
```

Only if I give an hardcoded model json into the template_login it works.

```
this.$el.html( this.template_login(  {username: "Joe"} ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems here were in two places. In the model code and in the rendering view code:

First, model should have defined the variables used in the template, at least by defaults as `null`.

Second, rendering code in the view should mention the model's attributes in the template function defined in the same view but not only the model.

Like so:

First,

in model file:

```
defaults: {
            username: "",//or alternately username: null,
        },
```

Second

in view file:

```
this.$el.html( this.template_login( this.loginModel.attributes ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that defining a variable in defaults is enough , i faced this problem before , for example for a calculated field in model 
in the inialize method i write :

```
 initialize : function() {
            this.set({
                "calculatedField" : this.calculateField()
            });
},
calculateField:function(){
       //calculate your field or return it directly
 }
```

and then you can use calculatedField normally in your template , if it is not a calculated field then it should be in your model as other fields returned by the rest service for example

Comment: But it does work now with null value, as well as with empty string.